# What is Starfleet's policy on using Telekinesis / Psychokinesis?

Tags: star-trek

Starfleet has many regulations about using technology (such as cloaking) and even abilities (telepathic information is not admissible at trial). Many episodes display Starfleet personnel using telekinesis/psychokinesis. Captain James Kirk [controlled the dwarf Alexander with his mind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Plato's_Stepchildren_(episode)) in 2268. In 2374 [Kes became so powerful](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gift_(episode)) her psychokinesis activated on only a thought against her will, making a hypospray fly across the room into the Doctor's hand. It appears nearly anyone can have these powers by simply eating the food of Platonis which was rich in [kironide](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kironide)

Telepaths and empaths are actually employed in Starfleet, but despite the clear utility of psychokinetic powers no one uses them routinely. Is this due to some regulation or treaty?

Comment: doesn't the power Alexander / Kirk use only come while *on* Platonis? Kes wasn't a Starfleet officer. Are there any other instances where someone demonstrated these abilities outside of a specific location?

Comment: @NKCampbell No according to McCoy it was the mineral in the food. Uhura and Chapel were forced to beam themselves down from orbit. I believe Kes was a member of starfleet even if not an officer. No rules?

Comment: Right - a plant....on the planet. No more kironide == no more power. Kes was found in the Delta Quadrant - a bit of a distance from Starfleet Academy. Don't confuse that she had a communicator and was riding along w/ Voyager to mean being a member of Starfleet.

Comment: Plants are not stuck on the planet? Like dilithium isn't?

Comment: *eyeroll* And, while not necessarily citing a law, Spock was certainly ready to torch Gary Mitchell when he [Mitchell] showed signs of ESP (which iirc included psychokinesis)

Comment: @NKCampbell:  Not merely ESP and psychokenisis, but that **and** a tendency to megalomania on Mitchell's part.  Even in the beginning, as his powers were still weak, he tended to use them to force things to his will.  **That's** what had Spock reaching for the phaser - together with the knowledge that the **last** ship it happened to was **also** taken over by a crewman with god delusions.

Comment: They seem fine with using Betazoid empathic abilities during counselling.

Comment: Kes was never a member of Starfleet. She joined Voyager on a field posting at a time where Voyager could not communicate with Starfleet, and left Voyager (at the end of season 3) before the crew first established communication with Starfleet (sometime during season 4). She never had a rank of any kind, let alone any Starfleet training and education beyond what she learned in the field. Starfleet never even knew she existed until after she left the ship.

Comment: This makes the assumption that Voyager has no authority to enlist SF members. SFR-03-8532-3892 specifically covers [emergency assignment of scientific and research personnel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_General_Orders_and_Regulations?file=Starfleet_transfer_regulations.jpg) (medical is the science division, Kes was a medical assistant). Regardless, as a crew member she still fell under whatever laws were in place on the ship - she can't just do anything she wants.